# "...обязать руководителей (лиц их замещающих)..."

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, определения, причастный-оборот

"...обязать руководителей (лиц их замещающих)..."

Нужна ли запятая после "лиц"?

Comment: Здесь из-за уточнения сказанное касается только "лиц, их замещающих". Надо так: *руководителей, а также лиц, их замещающих*.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, запятая нужна, так как здесь обособляется определительный оборот, стоящий после определяемого слова.

Во всех официальных документах (законы, указы президента и т.д.) запятая после слова "лиц" стоит всегда. В качестве примера загуглите "лиц, их замещающих".

Comment: А из Розенталя это не подходит? НЕ обособляются "стоящие после определяемого существительного, если последнее само по себе в данном предложении не выражает нужного смысла и нуждается в определении, например: Он мог услышать вещи для себя довольно неприятные, если бы неравно Грушницкий отгадал истину (Лермонтов) (сочетание мог услышать вещи не выражает нужного понятия); Чернышевский создал произведение в высшей степени оригинальное и чрезвычайно замечательное (Писарев;"

Comment: В вашем примере речь идет о сочетании "мог услышать вещи". Это все же немного другое.

Answer (score 0):

**...(лиц, их замещающих)...**

Запятая нужна, поскольку "их замещающих" — причастный оборот после определяемого слова.

Comment: Зачем же вам всем столько шелухи!

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой чё?

Comment: Многоточия, скобки. Они же маловажны для самого разбора. ;) Имел в виду автора и вас.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой а-а. Ну, чё она, то и я, а то чё, я ничё, а она чё?